# VARCHAR fields trucated to 255 chars

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I'm using PHP, SQL Server 2012, and FreeTDS. With TDS version = 7.4, all of my VARCHAR fields are being truncated to 255 characters.

I've read that this happens with TDS versions less than 7.0, so that does not apply to this configuration.

This was working correctly when we were using TDS version 7.1, but our hosting provider seems to have changed something (still working on figuring that out) and now we're unable to connect with 7.1 for some reason.

Here is the output of `tsql -C`:

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v1.00.27
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: auto
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
                            OpenSSL: yes
                             GnuTLS: no
                               MARS: no
```

And here is my freetds.conf:

```
[global]
    tds version = 7.4
    text size = 2147483647

[my-server-name]
    host = my-server-name
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.4
    instance = my-db-instance
```

I'm connecting via PHP (using the old `mssql_*` functions) using the same value I used for `my-server-name`. I've verified that it is using that configuration by changing the `tds version` to 7.1, with which the connection does not work.

I was previously using freetds v0.91 and I downloaded the latest stable version and followed the build instructions on their website to update, but it did not help the issue.

There is a very large number of tables, queries, stored procedures, and functions in this code base, so updating all calls to these VARCHAR fields to use something like a `CAST(column AS TEXT)` is not an option.

Sample code that shows the issue for me is as follows:

```
<?php
$conn = mssql_connect('my-server-name', 'my-username', 'my-password');
mssql_select_db('my-database', $conn);
$result = mssql_query("SELECT longFieldName FROM myTable");
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

And this is pulling from a table that was created as:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (longFieldName VARCHAR(2000));
INSERT INTO myTable (longFieldName) VALUES ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.');
```

When I run the PHP code, I expect the full string to be dumped, but instead, it outputs the following string:

```
array(1) {
  'longFieldName' =>
  string(255) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor i"
}
```

What is causing these fields to be truncated at 255 characters?

---

#### EDIT:

It appears this may be specific to PHP. I tried connecting using `tsql` and I did the query and got the full string back. I'm using PHP 5.5.15 (cli), I have xdebug set up with the following configuration:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/xdebug.so"
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
```

And the following MSSQL configuration:

```
[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.connect_timeout = 5
mssql.timeout = 6000000000
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
mssql.secure_connection = Off
```

---

#### UPDATE:

I do not see this issue with version 7.0. So to summarize what happens with each version:

- 7.0: Able to connect and varchar fields not truncated, but does not support 64-bit integers.
- 7.1: Not able to connect ([which is a separate issue](https://serverfault.com/q/843968/43378)). When we were able to connect in the past, we didn't have the truncation issue.
- 7.2 and up: Able to connect, but varchar fields are truncated.

Comment: where is your create table and insert/update statement?

Comment: When are the fields truncated? In SELECTs, INSERTs or UPDATEs? Show us the code doing the faulty operation.

Comment: Added sample code and table.

Comment: A few years ago, I faced a similar problem. But it was only about fetching a column with more than 255 characters which was converted to blob into MsSQL. It's only happened with Linux server connection SQL Server. Into your SQL server, is there the full string or the truncated one?

Comment: When log into SQL Server directly (in SSMS) and do the same query, I get the full string back.

Comment: Swinging in the dark here, but maybe try `mssql.textlimit = 2147483647` and `mssql.textsize = 2147483647` in php.ini?

Comment: @FlipperPA: Nope, same result.

Comment: Another thought: could PHP be using a different version of FreeTDS? Perhaps php-mssql was compiled with an older version of the library?

Comment: @FlipperPA: You're onto it. I figured this out yesterday but just connected the dots this morning. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've figured out the truncation issue.

While I attempted to update my FreeTDS version, I actually installed a second version of FreeTDS, and that is what was being used for `tsql -C`. But when I enabled logging by setting `dump file = /tmp/freetds.log` in my freetds.conf and then ran a test and looked at the log, the first line says:

```
Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.91
```

So PHP is actually using FreeTDS version 0.91. And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38361664/259457), 0.91 only supports up to TDS version 7.2.

So when I specified 7.3 or 7.4, I believe it was defaulting to an older version, which is confirmed by another line lower in the log file:

```
Connecting to 172.19.4.129 port 1433 (TDS version 4.2)
```

So this is the reason for the truncation issue. I'll have to update my version of FreeTDS that PHP is using.